# How to show profile page in another visual force page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am trying for call Profile page of saleforce.com into another visualforce page using

`<chatteranswer:allfeeds/>`

but its not showing profile page

please help me solve this issue..

Comment: Can you give me a screenshot of what this profile page is?

Comment: @jimbo, I can not post image due to less reputation in stackoverflow.com but if you have an salesforce account then you check profile page "Your Name > My Profile" or [link] (https://ap1.salesforce.com/_ui/core/userprofile/UserProfilePage?tab=sfdc.ProfilePlatformFeed)
replace your domain inplace of my.
Thank you

Comment: have made sure that you have provided the communityId? 


`<apex:page showHeader="false" >
      <chatteranswers:allfeeds communityId="09a90000000d1Af"/>
</apex:page>`